# Angular Mat Table Error: Missing definitions for header and row

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using MatTable from Angular Material 5.2.5. I trying to populate the table with data which is got through a server request.

The UI

```
  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="number">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>#</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let i = index">{{i + 1}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.userName}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    ...
  </mat-table>
```

The component code

```
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>()
  public displayedColumns = ['number', 'name', 'email', 'phone', 'joiningDate']
```

Adding data to dataSource on receiving data from the server

```
 onGettingPartnerUsers(userList: User[]) {
  console.log('userList', userList)
  if (!Util.isFilledArray(userList)) {
    // TODO show message no user found
  } else {
    this.dataSource.data = userList
  }
 }
```

I am getting the list of users. But this error is getting thrown.

```
Error: Missing definitions for header and row, cannot determine which columns should be rendered.
```

What is the mistake?

PS: I am following [this](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-material-part-4-data-table-23874582f23a) blog on using MatTable

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You must add `mat-row` and `mat-header-row`(optional) tags inside your table:

```
<mat-table>
  .... columns definitions

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

See more examples here https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Answer (score -2):

Add the following code:

```html
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

in the end before closing your table tag `</table>`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).