# Material design data table layout with static data

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, mat-tab

How can I use the material design data table layout without a datasource (static data)? I can find no example for this use case on https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples. For example I tried the following without success.

```
<mat-table>
 <mat-header-row>
  <mat-header-cell>One</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-header-cell>Two</mat-header-cell>
 </mat-header-row>
 <mat-row>
  <mat-cell>aaa</mat-cell>
  <mat-cell>bbb</mat-cell>
 </mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

I'am getting following error:

```
LeistungenComponent.html:195 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatCell -> CdkColumnDef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatCell -> CdkColumnDef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for CdkColumnDef!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:979)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1232)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1182)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1077)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1232)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1182)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1077)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:9238)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:9919)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:9238)
```

Comment: The first example on the [documentation page, which you have linked](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples), shows exactly how to do this with a simple data array.

Comment: @AndreasMayer That example is for material table with a datasource. Question is about how to use the material table without a datasource.

Comment: @Manoj De Mel: If you look at the TypeScript source of that example, you will see that it uses a plain array instead of a MatTableDataSource.

Comment: @AndreasMayer As I understand, the question is about "how to user Material Table" without a datasource He/She would like to use it like a normal table. As far as I know you cannot use Material Table without a datasource regardless it's a MatDataSource or otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

In your app.module.ts, add to providers

```
providers:[CdkColumnDef]
```

Add to the imports

```
import { CdkColumnDef } from '@angular/cdk/table';
```

Comment: Great it worked but now i am getting this error : 
Missing definitions for header, footer, and row; cannot determine which columns should be rendered

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026943/angular-mat-table-error-missing-definitions-for-header-and-row This should help

Comment: @VedhaPeri If someone want to make the table from static data, how it can be done?, If I am checking your link it's about datasource

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know you cannot use Material Table like a normal HTML table. You would need a datasource.

There are two ways to get the styles of Material Table though. You can either use 
 [Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#tables-section) or by using the css styles from Material Table.

Please refer to this Git Hub thread for solution.
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3805

```html
<style>
.mat-table {
  display: block;
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana;
}

.mat-row,
.mat-header-row {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 48px;
  padding: 0 24px;
}

.mat-cell,
.mat-header-cell {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>

<div class="mat-table">
  <div class="mat-header-row">
    <div class="mat-header-cell">One</div>
    <div class="mat-header-cell">Two</div>
    <div class="mat-header-cell">Three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mat-row">
    <div class="mat-cell">AAA</div>
    <div class="mat-cell">BBB</div>
    <div class="mat-cell">CCC</div>
  </div>
</div>
```