# Angular Material - Missing definitions for header, footer, and row; cannot determine which columns should be rendered

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am getting an error using Angular Material's table component. I have seen this question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026943/angular-mat-table-error-missing-definitions-for-header-and-row), but I am still getting the error even after doing what was suggested as a fix.

ERROR Error: Missing definitions for header, footer, and row; cannot determine which columns should be rendered.

This is my HTML code for the table:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="customers" class="mat-elevation-z8">

        <!-- Position Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer"> {{ customer?.name }} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Email">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Email </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer"> {{ customer?.email }} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Weight Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Phone number">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Phone number </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer"> {{ customer?.phone.number }} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Symbol Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Notes">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Notes </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer"> {{ customer?.notes }} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
```

Here is my component TypeScript file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from '../customers.types';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomersService } from '../customers.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss']
})
export class CustomersListComponent implements OnInit {
  customersSub: Subscription;
  detailsSub: Subscription;
  displayedColumns: string[] = [ 'Name', 'Email', 'Phone number', 'Notes' ];
  customers: Customer[] = [];
  customersLength: number;
  loadingMode: boolean = false;
  openDetailsDrawer: boolean = false;
  detailsId: string;

  constructor(private _router: Router,
              private _route: ActivatedRoute,
              public _customersService: CustomersService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.loadingMode = true;
      this._route.queryParams.subscribe(params =>{
          this.detailsId = this._route.snapshot.params['id'];
      });

      this._customersService.getCustomers();
      this.customersSub = this._customersService.getCustomersUpdateListener()
          .subscribe((customers: Customer[]) => {
              this.loadingMode = false;
              this.customers = customers;
              this.customersLength = customers.length;
      });

      this.detailsSub = this._customersService.getDetailsUpdateListener()
          .subscribe((bool: boolean) => {
              this.openDetailsDrawer = bool;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.detailsSub.unsubscribe()
  }

  onOpenDetails(_id: string) {
      this._customersService.openDetails(_id);
  }

  onOpenCreate() {
      this._customersService.openCreate();
  }

}
```

Comment: https://dev.to/jwp/angular-material-table-in-20-minutes-15f4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, not quite sure how or why. I restarted the client, which is something I have done several times without success. This time it made a difference though. I did not change any of the code. Now it works perfectly, with a static array of objects or with an observable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify columns array in your template, like this:

template file

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row> <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

and the controller file

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
```

Take a look to the all files in the examples:
https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Comment: That's what I am doing though. Did you not see my code? I've also tried using it the way you are doing without HTML table elements, and it doesn't change a thing. The error is still there.


My implementation is literally almost exactly how it is in the the example on https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples. The only difference is just what strings are being displayed.